# How do I override a syntax's comment character in a modeline, in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a weird assembler which uses `\` as a comment character. The standard vim `asm` syntax uses `#` as a comment character instead, which is bad because it's both wrong and `#` is an instruction delimiter in this instruction set (it's the 6502).

This is very niche, so it's not worth creating a new syntax file for. Instead I'd just like to change the comment character in the modeline for each assembler file.

I've tried:

```
\ vim: comments=:\\
```

...and while it's accepted, and I can see from doing `set comments` that it has been set, it doesn't actually do anything --- is the `comments` option actually taken into account by the syntax highlighting? If not, is there a way to override it in the modeline?

Comment: You may be better of asking at https://vi.stackexchange.com/. If you do that please delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

No, `:help 'comments'` is not taken into account by the syntax highlighting. Moreover, the pool of commands that are allowed in a modeline doesn't include `:help :syn-match`, which is the one you actually need, here.

Note that the alternative is *not* to write a whole syntax script. You should be able to achieve the desired result with these few (untested) lines in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup assembler
autocmd!
autocmd Syntax asm syn match asmComment "your pattern here" contains=asmTodo,@Spell
augroup END
```